# Designing one-to-one and one-to-many relationships in Spring Data R2DBC

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, spring-data-jdbc

I am exploring possible ideas when it comes to designing the one-to-one and one-to-many relationships while using Spring Data R2DBC.

As Spring Data R2DBC still do not support relationships natively there is still a need to handle those on our own (unlike Spring Data JDBC).

What I would imagine that when it comes to one-to-one mapping, the implementation could look like this:

```java
@Table("account")
public class Account {
    
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @Transient // one-to-one
    private Address address;
    }
```

```java
@Table("address")
public class Address {
    
    @Id
    private Integer id;
}
```

while the database schema would be defined as follows:

```sql
--address
CREATE TABLE address
(
    id                  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
)
    
--account
CREATE TABLE account
(
    id                     SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    address_id             INTEGER REFERENCES address(id)
)
```

As the `Account` object is my aggregate root what I would imagine is that I am supposed to load the `Address` object with it following the advice of Jens Schaduer:

> An aggregate is a cluster of objects that form a unit, which should
> always be consistent. Also, it should always get persisted (and
> loaded) together.
> source: [Spring Data JDBC, References, and Aggregates](https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/24/spring-data-jdbc-references-and-aggregates)

This leads me to thinking that in case of one-to-one relationships like this one I in fact should have my `Account` entity defined like this:

```java
@Table("account")
public class Account {
    
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @Transient // one-to-one
    private Address address;

    @Column("address_id")
    private Integer addressId;
}
```

and later on to recreate the full `Account` aggregate entity with an `Address` I would write something like:

```java
@Service
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {
    
    private final AccountRepository accountRepository;
    private final AddressRepository addressRepository;
    
    public AccountServiceImpl(AccountRepository accountRepository,
                              AddressRepository addressRepository) {
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
        this.addressRepository = addressRepository;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Mono<Account> loadAccount(Integer id) {
        return accountRepository.getAccountById(id)
            .flatMap(account ->
                 Mono.just(account)
                 .zipWith(addressRepository.getAddressByAccountId(account.getAddressId()))
                 .map(result -> {
                     result.getT1().setAddress(result.getT2());
                         return result.getT1();
                 })
        );
    }
}
```

If that is not the case, how else should I handle one-to-one relationships while using Spring Data R2DBC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your approach is reasonable. There are just a couple of nitpicks:

- Do you need the flatMap -> Mono.just ? Can't you just use `map` directly?
- I wouldn't consider this a service, but a repository (it's just not implemented by Spring Data directly.
- You might be able to that code in a after load callback.

Comment: If I use `map` then I am forced to `.block()`, no? In my case I am retrieving `addresses` from the database, thought `flatMap` is my only option here. Could you elaborate on your last remark?

Comment: you are probably correct about `map`.

Comment: I was thinking of an `AfterConvertCallback`. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/current/reference/html/#entity-callbacks

Comment: I was also looking for something similar, but instead of single account I have list of accounts. I also don't want the system to execute a query for each address.

Comment: @Harsha Me too which r2dbc doesn't support which pretty much makes r2dbc / webflux useless for RDMS. REALLY bad idea to have to write manual low level custom mapping code for complex objects.